# PHP Mailer change FROM NAME

Tags: php, email, html, phpmailer

I have managed to send a mail to myself using this code.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    //Email server info
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //User authentication info
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '******@hotmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '********';

    //Email info
    $mail->From = 'noreply@ledii.net';
    $mail->FromName = 'LediiNet';
    $mail->addAddress($mail->Username);
    $mail->Subject = 'LediiNet Feedback';
    $mail->Body = 'Here are some thoughts...';
```

Is it possible to make it so that the mail will show up with my website name as sender insteath of my name and email?

I would preferrably want it to seem like the mail is sent from noreply@ledii.net and with the sender name of LediiNet.

I feel like I probably have to actually create that email somehow and connect to my host servers email server info?

Comment: This may be an outlook.com restriction, so you might have to use a different SMTP service that allows you to use custom sender information.

Comment: A mailserver doesn't care about the sender information you give it. You could send an email from bill@gates.com if you'd like. Ofcourse mailservers like Outlook.com don't want their users to abuse this. Therefor you need to find a mailserver that has no problems with custom sender info. Basicly what Barmar said, but in more understandable English.

Comment: On a sidenote: May I suggest you remove that email address from your question? Webcrawlers love those for sending spam!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426744/send-email-and-insert-data-to-database-php-mysql/27426968#27426968

Comment: Either @vallicu's solution or you can modify the default outgoing email in your server to be noreply@example.com, which could be complicated if you are not experienced. See this article http://semi-legitimate.com/blog/item/how-to-rewrite-outgoing-address-in-postfix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, but I had to change to using the `mail()` function and modify my local files for it to work locally.